# Not all Wordpress pages are displaying menus correctly

Tags: wordpress

I am having a specific issue with my wordpress site that I'm trying to resolve.

The site is at [www.dontforgetthebubbles.com](http://www.dontforgetthebubbles.com)

As you will see the homepage looks fine.

But many posts are not displaying correctly.  As an example:

http://www.dontforgetthebubbles.com/2013/08/cradle-cap/#

1. The menu columns are all showing simultaneously (hover over 'Clinical' and compare this to the home page to see what I mean)
2. The 'toggle' button is not working (see http://www.dontforgetthebubbles.com/2013/07/intubating-with-stridor/ for an example of a post where it does work correctly).

I think the issues are related to more recent posts (and the older posts are ok) but it is affecting around 15 posts.

Could anyone suggest what my be causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a CSS or plugin causing conflict. I can see that you're loading many stylesheets. Probably have a lot of plugins? Try disabling them one by one, beginning with the most recently installed to narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

Check all the Javascript files. Looks like some are missing on the pages with the problems. For example, `superfish.js` or `sprite.js`. My guess is one of them handles the dynamic menu features with is why `<ul class="sub-menu">...</ul>` under Clinical doesn't have by default the `display:none` property unlike your home page.